# What does an Apache Beam Dataflow job do locally?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having some issues with an Apache Beam Python SDK defined Dataflow. If I step through my code it reaches the the pipeline.run() step which I assume means the execution graph was successfully defined. However, the job never registers on the Dataflow monitoring tool, which from [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc) makes me think it never reaches the pipeline validation step.

I'd like to know more about what happens between these two steps to help in debugging the issue. I see output indicating packages in my `requirements.txt` and `apache-beam` are getting pip installed and it seems like something is getting pickled before being sent to Google's servers. Why is that? If I already have apache-beam downloaded, why download it again? What exactly is getting pickled?

I'm not looking for a solution to my problem here, just trying to understand the process better.

Comment: For the pip installation of Apache Beam, do you have the latest versions installed on your machine? Does the installation throw any error?

Comment: I install the latest version into a virtual environment. For some reason the second apache-beam download would complain about not being able to find `nose` and quit. Installing `nose` into the virtual environment fixed that issue. Putting it in `requirements.txt` does not however. Not sure why it needs a testing package in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

During Graph Construction, Dataflow checks for errors and any illegal operations in the pipeline. Once the checks are successful, execution graph is translated into JSON and transmitted to Dataflow service. In Dataflow service the JSON graph is validated and it becomes a job.
However, if the pipeline is executed locally, the graph is not translated to JSON or transmitted to Dataflow service. So, the graph would not show up as a job in the monitoring tool, it will run on the local machine [1]. You can follow the documentation to configure the local machine [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#pipeline-lifecycle-from-pipeline-code-to-dataflow-job

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-local-execution

Comment: This calculation was set to use DataflowRunner, the pipeline should not be executing locally. I've dug into the code a little more since asking. The translation to JSON is where pickling comes in. The pipeline operations are serialized using `dill` and sent as part of a JSON request to Google's servers. I'm still not sure why I see a second copy of apache-beam getting downloaded locally though.

Comment: The default pipeline option for ‘sdk_location’ field allows the Beam SDK to download or copy the SDK from a specified location during Workflow submissions. Deleting the ‘default’ string value for the ‘sdk_location’ field and leaving it empty will result in SDK not copied [1].
  
[1] https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/#pipeline-options-for-the-cloud-dataflow-runner

Answer (score 1):

The packages from requirements.txt are downloaded using `pip download` and they are staged on to the staging location. This staging location will be used as cache by the Dataflow and is used to look up packages when `pip install -r requirements.txt` is called on Dataflow workers to reduce calls to the pypi.

Answer (score 0):

> > Why is that? If I already have apache-beam downloaded, why download it again? What exactly is getting pickled?

For the Runner v1, Dataflow uses containers built by Dataflow itself. So Beam downloads apache beam wheel and stages it to the staging location.

For Runner v2, this is not needed and is planned to remove in the version 2.50  - https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/26996.